# Why association don't working.Undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a polymorphic association between 3 models - User, Post and Comment.But in step when I associate User and Post and added form 'user_id' in view 'posts/index' browser show me an error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

this is my view posts/index.html.haml

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = post.title
  = post.body
  = post.user.name
```

this is my view posts/new.html.haml

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, placeholder: "title"
  = f.text_field :body, placeholder: "text"
  = f.text_field :user_id, placeholder: "user"
  = f.submit "Send"
```

this is my controller posts_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

this is my migration create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my model Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**UPD**

```
2.1.5 :001 > Post.all   Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "title", body: "body", user_id: nil, created_at: "2014-12-04 13:27:35", updated_at: "2014-12-04 13:27:35">, #<Post id: 2, title: "title", body: "body", user_id: nil, created_at: "2014-12-04 13:47:36", updated_at: "2014-12-04 13:47:36">, #<Post id: 3, title: "title", body: "body", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-12-04 13:50:50", updated_at: "2014-12-04 13:50:50">, #<Post id: 4, title: "title", body: "body", user_id: 2, created_at: "2014-12-04 13:57:15", updated_at: "2014-12-04 13:57:15">]> 
2.1.5 :002 >
```

how fix?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Try see if your all post have user_id present in console. Error says in your some post you don't have user_id set properly

Comment: `post.user` is nil. This means that the for that post, user_id is empty in the database.  Go to your app in the terminal and start rails console using `rails c`. Check if `Post.first.user` is nil.

Comment: Do you have a render template: 'new' in your posts index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does every have post a `user_id` filled in? I am guessing that is the error not. The simple workaround is to test if there is a user present, before looking for its name. So simply:

```
= post.user.name if post.user.present?
```

or, short and sweet:

```
= post.user.try(:name)
```